# Wie nennt man einen weiblichen Nazi?

Tags: usage, gender

Ich tue mir im Moment schwer, wie man eine Frau korrekt als Nazi bezeichnet.

Für Männer ist der Fall klar.

> Onkel Björn ist ein alter Nazi.

Aber für Frauen?

> Tante Alice ist ein alter Nazi. (?)
>
> Tante Alice ist eine alte Nazi. (?)
>
> Tante Alice war schon immer Nazi. (?)

Beides 'klingt™️' für mich verkehrt.

---

Bei meiner Recherche stieß ich auf Wörter wie

> [Nazistin](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nazistin)

oder

> [Nazisse](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nazisse)

Jedoch behaupte ich, dass beide Wörter im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch nahezu komplett unbekannt sind und daher ausscheiden. Dass das zweite dazu eher noch phonetisch mit der Blume verwechselt werden würde macht das Ganze nicht besser.

Einfacher wird es bei Wortkombinationen, die aber Unschärfe oder andere Bedeutungen reinbringen.

> Nazi-Sau, [Nazi-Schlampe](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/gesellschaft/medien/alice-weidel-verliert-gegen-extra3-vor-gericht-nazi-schlampe-ist-okay-weil-satire/19816018.html), [Nazi-Mädchen](https://www.welt.de/vermischtes/article174027527/Aussteigerin-Nazi-Maedchen-Benneckenstein-trifft-juedische-Gemeinde.html), [Nazi-Braut](https://www.welt.de/politik/deutschland/article111216797/Heimliche-Drahtzieherin-statt-nur-Nazi-Braut.html)

Wobei auch das letztere eher die Braut eines Nazis bezeichnet, statt dass die Frau der (oder die?) Nazi ist.

Das einzige Beispiel das ich fand war [folgender Artikel](https://www.spiegel.de/einestages/tod-von-gudrun-burwitz-heinrich-himmlers-tochter-nazi-bis-zuletzt-a-1215755.html)

> Himmlers Tochter "Püppi" - Nazi bis zuletzt

Dieser umgeht allerdings auch den Artikel.

---

Also ... wie bezeichne ist eine Frau am einfachsten, am verständlichsten und grammatikalisch richtig als Nazi? Vorzugsweise mit Links zu Beispielen in (richtigen) Veröffentlichungen ;) .

Comment: Warum reklamierst du das Wort *klingen* für Dich als eingetragenes Warenzeichen?

Comment: Ich wusste gar nicht, dass es *-Nazis gibt, die auf sowas Wert legen. Wieder was gelernt.

Comment: Zu den ersten beiden Treffern Deiner Suche: Nicht nur wäre bei Nazisse Verwechslungsgefahr mit der Blume gegeben, Nazistin würde man leicht als "Narzisstin" missverstehen, was zwar auch negativ wäre, aber in anderer Hinsicht als vom Sprecher gemeint.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Als neue Einnahmequelle, weils bisher noch niemand sonst gemacht hat und als humoristischen Einschub ;)

Comment: ** *Nazette* **

Comment: @mtwde weil es so schön klingt (klimpert), wenn wieder eine Münze eingezahlt wird? :-D

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf [Ganz genau](https://cafart.r.worldssl.net/images/Category_253/subcat_30836/imgrosascrooge027.jpg) ^^

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ganz allgemein gesprochen ist in diesem Kontext, also wenn es um [Prädikative](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4dikativum) geht, [Movierung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movierung) nicht nötig. Viele Sprecher nehmen keinen Anstoß an Sätzen wie den folgenden, wo das Geschlecht (Sexus) durch das Subjekt gekennzeichnet wird.

> Sie ist Professor/Informatiker/Nazi/…

Belege:

> Denn sie war Nazi, geboren in der elitären Naziszene in Bayern. ([FAZ](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/buecher/themen/heidi-benneckenstein-und-deborah-feldman-im-streitgespraech-15257559.html))
>
> Er hatte Soubry vor dem Parlament mit einer Kamera verfolgt, und sie als Nazi und Verräterin beschimpft. ([Welt](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/buecher/themen/heidi-benneckenstein-und-deborah-feldman-im-streitgespraech-15257559.html))
>
> Sie war ein Nazi (Werner, [*Liebesglück*](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&id=3mkvDwAAQBAJ&q="sie+war+ein+Nazi"))
>
> Die Einzige, die sich zu Wort gemeldet hat, war meine Großmutter, die war kein Nazi (Crha, [*Österreicher im II. Weltkrieg*](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&id=K30hAQAAIAAJ&q="die+war+kein+Nazi"))
>
> Es geht gar nicht darum, sie als einen Nazi zu dekuvrieren. ([Deutsche Welle](https://www.dw.com/de/goebbels-sekret%C3%A4rin-hat-nichts-gewusst-ein-deutsches-leben/a-38259655))

Besteht das Bedürfnis nach Movierung, kann man auf die Vollform zurückgreifen: *Nationalsozialistin*.

Kurzwortbildungen fehlt im allgemeinen die Möglichkeit zur Movierung. Vielleicht ist das der Grund, warum eine Form wie *Nazistin* auf Ablehnung stößt. Formen wie *Profistin, Ossistin* sind meines Wissens nicht im Gebrauch.

> Sie ist ein echter Profi, sie ist Realo, sie ist ein Ossi

Ausnahme (vom Duden als *scherzhaft* charakterisiert):

> die Azubine

Answer (score 5):

Ich glaube da gibt's keinen geschlechtsspezifischen Unterschied.

*Nazi* bezeichnet einen Menschen, der der nationalsozialistischen Ideologie anhängt.

> Aber für Frauen?
>
> > Tante Alice ist ein alter Nazi. (?)

ist fein für mich. Es benötigt keine geschlechtsspezifische Bezeichnung.

Wie im Kommentar angemerkt, ist *Reenie* manchmal die korrekte Bezeichnung für Neonazi-Bräute dieser Tage.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Siehe auch [Wer sind die Frauen der braunen Bande?](https://www.antifa.ch/wer-sind-die-frauen-der-braunen-bande/)</sub>

Comment: Korrekt, siehe auch hier: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nazi Synonyme dazu umfassen sowohl weibliche als auch männliche Formen. Es ist also klar beides gemeint.

Comment: Abgesehen davon, dass Neonazis oft keine Skinheads sind, Skinheads teils keine Neonazis, der Link nicht deutlich macht, ob es um die sog. Bräute der Skinheads geht oder ob diese selbst Nazis sind, abgesehen von all dem habe ich den Begriff Reenie noch nie gehört oder gelesen und halte die Aussage, dass das die korrekte Bezeichnung sei für sehr weit hergeholt. Ist das deren Selbstbezeichnung, ausschließlich deren Selbstbezeichnung oder ausschließlich eine Fremdbezeichnung?

Comment: @userunknown Nein, _Reenie_ ist schon seit Jahrzehnten ein weit verbreitetes Synonym für _Nazi-Schlampe_.

Comment: Also auch, wenn die Frau kein Skinhead ist, aber nicht, wenn sie zwar Skinhead aber kein Nazi ist?

Comment: @user Hmm, das ist ein guter Einwand. Skinheads sind nicht zwingend Nazis und umgekehrt. Die Oi-Culture ist ein wenig divers diesbezüglich.

Comment: @user I finde sie ja auch oft niedlich mit ihren undercuts und den gefärbten Strähnen. Sie lassen sich meistens auch gut manipulieren und komplett umdrehen :-D

Comment: Die Google-Bildersuche zeigt mir keine Frauen mit Glatze, sondern allenfalls Frauen, die womöglich mit männlichen Glatzen verkehren. Fragen über Fragen. Reenie soll auch der Diminutiv für Doreen, Irene und Maureen sein, was den Begriff m.E. ungeeignet macht, um ihn für politische Ansichten oder Cliquenzugehörigkeit einzusetzen. Alle Frauen und Mädchen, die zufällig so heißen, müssen sich dadurch ja zu unrecht vereinnahmt fühlen.

Comment: @user Um Gottes Willen! Keine Glatze, Undercut!

Comment: Der Schweizer Artikel sagte, Reenie sei der englische Ausdruck für weibliche Skinheads. Skinheads sind in meinem Sprachverständnis Glatzen, also Personen, die Glatze tragen, insbesondere solche, die einer Subkultur/Szene/Clique angehören, in der sehr viele Glatze tragen, und zwar freiwillig.

Comment: Der Reenie-Begriff war mir bislang auch noch unbekannt. Danke dafür. Wie in den anderen Kommentaren erwähnt könnte der zwar eher das weibliche Pendant zum Skinhead sein (und damit nicht für alle Nazi-Frauen passen), aber er geht zumindest in die Richtung.

Comment: @mtwde Ja, ich habe da auch ein wenig dazugelernt. _Reenie_ bezeichnet vor allem weibliche Skinheads (die auch nicht unbedingt wirklich Glatzen sondern eher Undercuts als Frisur bevorzugen). In der Kultur von Skinheads gibt es sowohl rechte, linke, als auch völlig unpolitische. Als allgemeine Bezeichnung kann der Begriff so wohl nicht herhalten.

Comment: @userunknown ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 3):

Ein exactes, wenn auch unschmeichelhaftes Wörtchen existiert, wird wenigstens in links-alternativen Kreisen auch noch immer gern gebraucht, und es gälte dieses zu recognisziren:

> Was eine ***[Nazisse](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Nazisse)*** war, war vor einem halben Jahrhundert jedem Deutschen geläufig.
>   <sub>Süddeutsche Zeitung, 24.07.1999</sub>
>
> ## Nazisse
>
> Worttrennung    Na-zis-se
>   Duden GWDS, 1999
>   Bedeutung
>   selten, umgangssprachlich, abwertend Anhängerin des Nationalsozialismus

Denn warum sollte irgendjemand Verbrecher *auf*werten wollen?

Dabei ist außerdem zu beachten, dass bereits *Nazi* eine – nicht nur ursprünglich sondern allezeit – sich auf einen [provinciellen Dummkopf beziehende Abwertung](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/43513/41728) darstellt. Nazis mögen es in aller Regel nicht, als Nazis bezeichnet zu werden. Ob Hitler oder Gauland. Wortkmobinationen sind in männlichem wie weiblichen nicht nur einfach, sondern einfach unnötig.

Nazisse ist daher der gesuchte Ausdruck. Jedenfalls wenn diese Personenkategorisierung korrekt gegendert werden soll.

Falls es kreativer werden soll, die bisherigen Vorschläge nicht ausreichen, böte sich noch [Hitlerowka an?](https://books.google.de/books?id=lZNdDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA342&dq=Nazisse&pg=PA342). Das sollte einerseits sofort verständlich sein, autokorrekturfest gegenüber Blumen, und hat durch slawischen Einschlag eine herrenmenschliche Ironie.

---

<sub>Um Nazisympathisanten zu besänftigen, wurde Bismarcksche Orthographie verwandt.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Die Formulierung "Sie ist eine Nazi" klingt zugegebenermaßen merkwürdig. Anderseits ist "Nazi" eine Abkürzung für "Nationalsozialist". Warum eine andere Abkürzung für "Nationalsozialistin"? Damit man das Geschlecht sofort auch an der Abkürzung ablesen kann?

Wenn man das durchdenkt, müssten Abkürzungen generell gegendert werden. Andere Fälle sind Sozi, Studi, Azubi, Schupo, Proll (oder Prolo) usw.

Meiner Meinung nach wäre das übertrieben und würde nur *noch merkwürdiger* klingende Bezeichnungen produzieren ("sie ist ein Nazin"). Außerdem müssten auch die Pluralformen gegendert werden. Statt "Als die Nazis an die Macht kamen" dann besser "Als die Nazis und Nazinnen an die Macht kamen"?

Ein interessanter Fall ist "der / die Auszubildende". Ist dann "der / die Azubi" richtig oder muss die weibliche Form anders lauten? Mit anderen Worten, soll ein Begriff, der gewollt geschlechsneutral ist, beim Abkürzen doch wieder gegendert werden?

Answer (score 1):

Als direktes weibliches Pendant würde ich ebenfalls [Nazistin](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nazistin) sehen.
Wenn es aber um einen möglichst natürlichen Sprachgebrauch geht, ergibt meiner Meinung nach "**Nationalsozialistin**" Sinn, da es sich bei "**Nazi**" lediglich um ein Kurzwort zu "**Nationalsozialist**" handelt.

---

Korrektur (angestoßen durch infinitezeros Kommentar):
Die Annahme, dass Nazi die Kurzform von Nationalsozialist ist, enstammt ebenfalls diesem Eintrag im Duden https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nazi, allerdings dürften genau genommen Nazist und Nazistin ein Wortpaar bilden, während Nazi wohl Nationalsozialist und Nationalsozialistin gleichermaßen abkürzt.

Comment: Warum kann Nazi nicht Kurzwort für den Nationalsozialisten als auch die Nationalsozialistin sein?

Comment: @infinitezero Eine berechtigte Frage. Ich habe meine Antwort entsprechend erweitert.

Answer (score 0):

Man kann auch sagen: Er / Sie ist ein Nazi-Aktivist. 
Oder: Tante Alice ist eine alte Nazi-Aktivistin.

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt keine einheitliche Movierung von Kurzwörtern auf *-i*. Allerdings sind für manche davon heutzutage zumindest scherzhaft weibliche Formen auf ***-ine*** nicht unüblich. Die meines Erachtens populärste und möglicherweise erste Bildung dieser Art ist

- *Azubine* < *Azubi* / *Auszubildende*.

Es ist zu vermuten, dass sowohl das geläufige Wort *Biene* als auch der allgemein bekannte Vorname *Sabine* und vor allem die Endung der Vollform auf *-e* einen Einfluss auf Bildung und Akzeptanz dieser Kurzform gehabt haben.

Gerade im studentisch-akademischen Kontext sind weitere Bildungen gebräuchlich, die allerdings überwiegend nicht auf substantivierte Partizipien oder Adjektive zurückgehen:

- *Hiwine* < *Hiwi* < *Hilfswissenschaftler*
- *Sprawine* < *Sprawi* < *Sprachwissenschaft(ler/student)*
- *Kowine* < *Kowi* < *Kommunikationswissenschaft(ler/student)*
- *Erstine* < *Ersti* < *Erstsemester(student)*
- *Maschine* < *Maschi* < *Maschinenbau(er/student)*
- *Etine* < *Eti* / *ETi* < *Elektrotechnik(er/student)*
- *Bufdine* < *Bufdi* < *Bundesfreiwilligendienst(leistender)*

Bei diesen Beispielen hat offensichtlich keine direkte Kürzung der weiblich movierten Langform auf *-in* stattgefunden, sondern die maskuline Kurzform auf *-i* wurde auf *-ine* erweitert.

Mit dieser morphologischen Systematik ist

- ***Nazine*** < *Nazi* < *Nationalsozialist*

daher prinzipiell möglich, aber (bisher?) ungebräuchlich. Die bereits genannten Bildungen

- ***Nazisse*** < *Nazi* < *Nationalsozialist*
- ***Nazistin*** < (?*Nazist* / *Nationalsozialistin*) < *Nationalsozialist*

sind meines Wissens heute viel weniger gebräuchlich als in der Mitte des 20. Jahrhunderts und haben nicht zu analogen Bildungen (**Azubisse*, **Sozistin*) geführt.

In einzelnen Fällen ist auch schon eine ansonsten unübliche Erweiterung der Movierung zur explizit männlichen Bezeichnung zu beobachten, bspw.:

- *Azubian* < *Azubi*
- *Hiwian* < *Hiwi*

Diese Parallelbildungen dürften auf eine (unbewusste) Analogie zu Vornamenpaaren wie *Christine* : *Christian* zurückgehen.

Es gibt übrigens eine Kurzform, für die sich die Movierung aus semantischen Gründen verbietet, da es prinzipbedingt keine weiblichen Tokens gab:

- ?*Zivine* < *Zivi* < *Zivildienst(leistender)*

Ähnliches gilt für ein morphologisches Kurzwort, für das keine geläufige Langform existiert, und v.a. als Antonym zu *Zivi* üblich gewesen ist, heute aber genereller verwendet wird und daher prinzipiell auch eine weibliche Movierung zulassen sollte:

- ?*Bundine* < *Bundi* < ?*Bundeswehrler* ‚Wehrdienstleistender‘ / ‚Bundeswehrsoldat‘

Zudem sollte erwähnt werden, dass viele der informellen maskulinen Kurzwörter auf *-i* auch intuitiv mit *-ie* (vgl. *Barbie*) oder *-y* (vgl. *Baby*) geschrieben werden.

Andere Kurzwörter auf *-i*, die ggf. genauso moviert werden könnten, sind bspw.:

- *Sozi* < *Sozial(ist/demokrat)*
- *Fundi* < *Fundamentalist*

Während Kurzwörter auf *-i* regulär den transparenten S-Plural bilden, ist ausschließlich für *Sozi* auch der N-Plural der Langform üblich: *Sozen* < *Sozialdemokraten*.

Answer (score -1):

In der Praxis vermeidet man - nach meinem Eindruck - Sätze wie *Sie ist ein Nazi*. Wenn man *Nationalsozialistin*  aus verschiedenen Gründen nicht verwenden will, weicht man eher aus auf Formulierungen wie:

> Sie gehört zu den Nazis.
>
> Sie gehört den Nazis an.
>
> Sie macht bei den Nazis mit.
>
> Sie ist bei den Nazis.

(Dies alles für die mündliche Alltagssprache, nicht für wissenschaftliche Abhandlungen.)

---

PS: Siehe dazu aber auch die andere Meintung von infinitezero unten bei den Kommentaren.

Comment: Gibt es einen Beleg dafür, dass man das in der Praxis vermeidet? Ich tue das nicht.

Comment: @infinitezero  Ja, gut, natürlich, ich kann nur berichten, was ich selbst um mich herum erlebe. In anderen Ecken des Landes und der Gesellschaft mag es durchaus anders sein. - Grundsätzlich ist es schwierig, Nachweise der Nichtexistenz von Dingen zu führen.