# Femininum für "Spezi"?

Tags: single-word-request

Gibt es ein feminines Äquivalent für das süddeutsche/österreichische *Spezi*?

> Peter is mei Spezl.
>
> Anna ist …..... (?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wie nennt man einen weiblichen Nazi?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53816/wie-nennt-man-einen-weiblichen-nazi)

Comment: @infinitezero: Ist "Spezi" denn eine Abkürzung?

Comment: wiktionary lists [spezieller Freund](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Spezi) and [Spezialfreund](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Spezi)

Comment: Soviel ich weiß, sagt man das nur unter Männern. Also Antwort, nein.

Comment: Nach [Boarischer Wikipedia](https://bar.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spezl): "A Spezl, aa Spezi, is a Mo, mit dem wo a andara Mo befreindet is. Fraun san (in da Regl) koane Spezln und hom koane Spezln."

Comment: @some_user ois klor, dang schee =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Wörter *Spezi* und vor allen *Spezl* werden in Bayern verwendet, vielleicht noch jenen österreichischen Regionen, die geographisch nahe an Bayern liegen (ich glaube in Salzburg sagt man auch noch so), sonst aber in Österreich eher seltener.

Verwendet werden diese Wörter ausschließlich für männliche Freunde. Die Frage, ob es ein weibliches Äquivalent gibt, hängt davon ab, wie man *»Äquivalent«* in diesem Fall definiert. Ich denke, in den meisten Fällen wird man das sagen:

> Anna ist meine beste Freundin.

Im Internet kursieren dutzende verschiedene Abkürzungen für Variationen davon, die man auch nach *»Anna ist ...«* einsetzen kann:

- ABF = Allerbeste Freundin
- ABFFIUE = Allerbeste Freundin für immer und ewig
- BFF = best friend forever

Aber diese Abkürzungen sind meist nur auf Cliquen beschränkt, werden allgemein nicht verstanden und haben meiner Einschätzung nach auch nicht das Potential, sich allgemein durchzusetzen.

---

Im Österreich ist seit geschätzten 20 oder 30 Jahren das Wort *»Oida«* (Dialektwort für *»Alter«*) als saloppe Anrede für einen Freund (manchmal auch als Anrede für jedermann, dann aber oft abwertend gemeint) in Verwendung:

> Seawas Oida, wia geht's da? (Sei gegrüßt Freund, wie geht es dir?)

Das interessante dabei ist, dass dieses eigentlich männliche Worte auch verwendet wird um weibliche Freundinnen anzureden. Das weibliche Dialektwort für *»Alte«* ist nämlich *»Oide«,* in der Anrede sagt man trotzdem auch zu Frauen *»Oida«.*

Als Bezeichnung (also nicht als Anrede) für einen Freund war lange Zeit vor allem im Großraum Wien das Wort *»Hawara«* in Verwendung. Die davon abgeleiteten Formen *»Hawi«, »Habschi«* usw. sind(waren) in ganz Österreich verbreitet, sterben gegenwärtig aber langsam wieder aus und werden vor allem von der jüngeren Bevölkerung nur noch vereinzelt verwendet. Eine 1971 erschienene Dialektübersetzung des Neuen Testaments trägt daher auch den Titel [Da Jesus & seine Hawara](https://www.residenzverlag.com/buch/da-jesus-seine-hawara-2). Aber auch dieses Wort existiert, wie der bayrische *Spezl* nur als Bezeichnung für männliche Freunde.

Comment: Im englischen Sprachraum sagen teenager auch "bae": ("an affectionate term used to address or refer to one’s girlfriend, boyfriend, spouse, etc.: dictionary.com) Ich weiss nicht, ob das auch im Deutschen verwendet wird (wie BFF).

Comment: Zu Zeiten des Patriarchats gab es Spezis und Amigos nur unter Männern. Inzwischen gibt es das Phänomen des Spezitums aber auch unter Frauen bzw. zwischen Frauen und Männern. Nur nennt man es heutzutage "networking". Aber ich plädiere dennoch für ein gendering des Spezis ;-)